# How to scroll background with Skrollr.js

Tags: jquery, html, skrollr

I have a problem with skrollr.js plugin. I want to change background position while scrolling.
I want to get an effect like for e.g. in this template: http://themes.lucky-roo.com/rinjani-v1.3.1/rj-parallax/index.html in "Little Known Facts!" section.

I divided my site into `<section>`. Each section has `position: relative`

Then I create a new section where I tried implement that animation with background image and try to change background-position but it don't work :/

```
<section class = "why-we-both white padding" 
    style = "background: #000 url ('img / bg1.jpg') no-repeat;"
    data-1000 = "background-position: 0 0"
    data-1200 = "background-position: 0 -400px">
...
</section>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try adding data-0 = "background-position: 0 0"  Skrollr kinda needs to know how an element is at position 0,